# Error converting java.lang.string to JSONArray

Tags: java, php

I've got a function that should retrieve an array of names from datbase and put result in a spinner.

But I get error org.json.JSONException: Value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

**My Java:**

```
public void onPostExecute(String h){
            super.onPostExecute(h);


    try{
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(h);
        ArrayList<String> HorseList = new ArrayList<>();
       


        //getting the user from the response
        JSONArray jArray = obj.getJSONArray("horse"); <-- error here
        
        for(int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++){
            JSONObject jObj = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            HorseList.add(jObj.getString("name"));

        }

        SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).saveArrayList(HorseList, "horselist");
        userLogin();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            //creating request handler object
            RequestHandler requestHandler = new RequestHandler();

            //creating request parameters
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("username", username);

            //returning the response
            return requestHandler.sendPostRequest(URLs.URL_GETHORSE, params);
        }
    }
```

**My PHP:**

```
  $username = $_POST['username'];
            //creating the query 
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT name FROM additional_user_info WHERE username = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param("s",$username);
            
            $stmt->execute();
            $result = $stmt->get_result();

            
            $json = [];

           if($result->num_rows > 0){
              while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                 $horse[] = array(
                    'name' => $row["name"]
                    );
                    
              }
           } 
           $json = json_encode($horse);


            $response['horse'] = $json;
```

The array looks like this:
[{"horse":"[{"name":"test"},{"name":"test2"},{"name":"test3"}]"}]

**Logcat:**

```
12-05 18:18:38.315 13936-13936/com.sebastianstext.pegasusbeta I/tagconvertstr: [{"horse":"[{\"name\":\"test\"},{\"name\":\"test2\"},{\"name\":\"test3\"}]"}]
12-05 18:18:38.315 13936-13936/com.sebastianstext.pegasusbeta W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value [{"name":"test"},{"name":"test2"},{"name":"test3"}] at horse of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
12-05 18:18:38.315 13936-13936/com.sebastianstext.pegasusbeta W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100)
12-05 18:18:38.315 13936-13936/com.sebastianstext.pegasusbeta W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:588)
12-05 18:18:38.315 13936-13936/com.sebastianstext.pegasusbeta W/System.err:     at com.sebastianstext.pegasusbeta.UserRelatedClasses.LoginActivity$1GetHorse.onPostExecute(LoginActivity.java:174)
12-05 18:18:38.315 13936-13936/com.sebastianstext.pegasusbeta W/System.err:     at com.sebastianstext.pegasusbeta.UserRelatedClasses.LoginActivity$1GetHorse.onPostExecute(LoginActivity.java:157)
12-05 18:18:38.315 13936-13936/com.sebastianstext.pegasusbeta W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
12-05 18:18:38.315 13936-13936/com.sebastianstext.pegasusbeta W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
12-05 18:18:38.316 13936-13936/com.sebastianstext.pegasusbeta W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
12-05 18:18:38.316 13936-13936/com.sebastianstext.pegasusbeta W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-05 18:18:38.316 13936-13936/com.sebastianstext.pegasusbeta W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
12-05 18:18:38.316 13936-13936/com.sebastianstext.pegasusbeta W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
12-05 18:18:38.316 13936-13936/com.sebastianstext.pegasusbeta W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-05 18:18:38.316 13936-13936/com.sebastianstext.pegasusbeta W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
12-05 18:18:38.316 13936-13936/com.sebastianstext.pegasusbeta W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
12-05 18:18:38.316 13936-13936/com.sebastianstext.pegasusbeta W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: Looks to me like you have errors in your JSON array.  This: `"{\"horse\":[{\"name\":\"test\"},{\"name\":\"test2\"},{\"name\":\"test3\"}]}"` works for me with the posted code (removed the outer `[` and `]`, which makes it a `JSONArray` rather than a `JSONObject`).

Comment: Tried to remove it but still get error, in jsonlint.com "[{"name":"test"},{"name":"test2"},{"name":"test3"}]" is a valid json string but the JSONArray wont take it.

Comment: That isn't a valid java string.  Need to escape the inner double quotes: `"[{\"name\":\"test\"},{\"name\":\"test2\"},{\"name\":\"test3\"}]" `

Comment: I get this `{"horse":"[{\"name\":\"test\"},{\"name\":\"test2\"},{\"name\":\"test3\"}]"}` with `Log.i` but the error message shows `[{"name":"test"},{"name":"test2"},{"name":"test3"}]`

Comment: `{"horse":...` is a `JSONObject`

Comment: Okey that solved my issue! Thank you very much for the assist!